# Compared to SQL what does this formula do

Tags: sql, math

A – ( B  ∩  A )

I was wondering what this set of mathematics can translate to when looking at,comparing it with SQL (operators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `A` and `B` are tables of the same "type" (same number of columns and compatible datatypes on corresponding columns), this can be translated to SQL like this:

```
A EXCEPT (A INTERSECT B)
```

which is of course equivalent (both in set and relational algebra) to:

```
A EXCEPT B
```

---

If `A` and `B` are tables of **different** "type", then set operations **do not make sense** between them. (Joins are something different, they should not be confused with Unions, Differences or Intersections, no matter how popular a link that "explains" them is.)

The fact that Unions, Differences and Intersections can also be expressed in several ways (using `(LEFT) JOIN`, `(NOT) IN`, `(NOT) EXISTS` combinations, besides the explicit `UNION`, `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT` operators) does not change that.

---

The syntax is not exactly as above. One can use either (works in Postgres and SQL-Server. It also works in Oracle if one replaces `EXCEPT` with `MINUS`):

```
  SELECT *
  FROM a

EXCEPT 

  ( SELECT * 
    FROM a
  INTERSECT
    SELECT *
    FROM b
  ) ;
```

or this (works in Postgres 8.4 and above: **[SQL-Fiddle test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/6cd8c/10)**)

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( TABLE a
  EXCEPT 
    ( TABLE a INTERSECT TABLE b ) 
  ) t  ;
```

and even this (*Look ma, no `SELECT`!*):

```
 TABLE a
EXCEPT 
  ( TABLE a  INTERSECT  TABLE b ) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to give another option in terms of SQL:

```
SELECT id FROM A
MINUS
SELECT id FROM B
```

**UPD:**

Beware that `MINUS` removes duplicates from the final result set and only exists in Oracle.

SQL standard uses EXCEPT which is supported by other vendors:

```
SELECT id FROM A
EXCEPT
SELECT id FROM B
```

In standard it has `DISTINCT` option which should remove dupes. I guess you will have to check docs of s specific vendor to see if duplicates will be removed. For example SQL Server's implementation of `EXCEPT` is the same as `MINUS` in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

This computes the set difference of A and B and in mats is also equivelent to `A - B`. So what you are interested in here are the elements in A that are not in B.

You can have a look at [this blog post](http://nimal.info/blog/2007/intersection-and-set-difference-in-mysql-a-workaround-for-except/) to see how set difference can be done in mysql.

Comment: so what you are saying A-B also means NOT IN mysql?

Comment: Well it means results in set A that are not in set B, so depending on the dialekt it might be NOT EXISTS for instance.

Answer (score 0):

That would be SET A MINUS (SET A INNER JOIN SET B). You are taking the records that occur in both A and B (INNER JOIN), then removing those from SET A (MINUS)

The intersecting in set theory terms is equivilant to INNER JOIN in SQL terms.

Edit: As for your question about being the same as NOT IN, not really. NOT IN is an operator used on column values ('selection'). The MINUS, JOIN, etc are set operators to perform operations between sets of rows.

Answer (score 0):

`A – ( B ∩ A )` equivalent is `A LEFT OUTER JOIN B WHERE TableB.id IS null`

[image]

[REFERENCE link HERE](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Another option will be to use

```
SELECT * FROM A 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B WHERE A.Id = B.id)
```

Comment: I added NOT Exists option to make it even more relevant to the question if you don't mind.

Comment: how about NOT IN and then use a subselect

Comment: To be honest, I haven't decided yet whether to downvote or not. The diagrams (you added here) and in the reference link you provided are indeed describing Unions, Differences and Intersections. The problem is that they are NOT describing joins. They have relevance to joins but there are (subtle and not) differences. So, despite that article has nice diagrams indeed, it adds confusion to those who read it and are novices in set and relational theory.

Comment: it describes as well the joins

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion but even in that page, it states: *"There's also a cartesian product or `cross join`, which as far as I can tell, **can't be expressed as a Venn diagram**:"*. As far as I know `a CROSS JOIN b` is equivalent to `a JOIN b ON 1=1` which makes `JOIN` not expressible (at least always) with Venn diagrams, too.

Comment: @hamchi [here](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) how to use  between `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` and `left join/is null`

Comment: Please avoid using Venn diagrams as tools to interpret JOIN operations.  Venn Diagrams are only suitable for basic set operations.  Not only can all join operations not be represented as Venn diagrams, typically JOIN operations are used on sets of unlike entities.

Comment: @CadeRoux though generally speaking you are right, diagram is fine in the answer to this question - `A – ( B ∩ A )`

Comment: @Bulat: The diagram alone is fine as an answer to the question, but the subsequent sentence is not complete enough: "A – ( B ∩ A ) equivalent is A LEFT OUTER JOIN B WHERE TableB.id IS null".  A and B in that statement have to be entities of the same time and thus should be two projections or instances of the same relation.  This is why I voted up ypercube's answer and yours does well to use standard set operations.  Such set operations CAN be done with (self)JOINs, but Venn diagrams do not have a very significant useful place in explaining SQL, I feel.

Comment: @CadeRoux ok, I agree that `A` and `B` must be of the same type. Once that is in place Venn diagrams are very handy. They are even used in analytic/segmentation tools, because everybody get's them. I will update the answer to make it as clear as Russian vodka.